# Android, копирование файлов

Tags: java, android

Есть следующее **задание**

> На Activity имеется кнопка Копировать, при нажатии на которую
>   производится копирование всех файлов каталога приложения на SD карту в
>   директорию, указанную в поле ввода.

Я так понял, что надо скопировать вообще все файлы проекта.
Есть следующий **метод для копирования файла**

```
public void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally {
        if(source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть **метод получения всех файлов в директории**

```
public ArrayList<File> listFilesWithSubFolders(File dir) {
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory())
                files.addAll(listFilesWithSubFolders(file));
            else
                files.add(file);
        }
        return files;
    }
```

Но я не знаю, как получить саму папку с приложением для того, чтобы передать ее в метод `listFilesWithSubFolders(File dir)`. Eсть метод `getApplicationInfo().dataDir`, но он возвращает String, а мне нужен File.
Есть ли способ решить это? Или есть пути лучше этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File fileDir = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir);
```

Comment: Пробовал так, к сожалению по пути getApplicationInfo().dataDir ничего нет, ни одного файла. Наверное нужно что-то другое

Comment: Конечно ничего нет, у Вас небось никаких даже настроек в приложении нет. Какую директорию копировать нужно-то?

Comment: Ну вот в задание написано "копирование всех файлов каталога приложения", я честно сам не очень понимаю, что от меня хотят, но спросить сейчас не могу. Думаю нужно скопировать **app** директорию приложения. Если это вообще возможно.